# How to assign a value to a variable declared on the heap in c?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, malloc, heap-memory

i am new to c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int *var = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 2)  ;

    *var = 22;

    printf("%d \n" , var);

    free(var);

    return 0;
}
```

is this the right way to assign a value to a variable created using malloc? because i've been trying to give it a value by doing

```
var = 22;
```

because when creating a 'string' in c and assigning a value to it it is done like this

```
char *var;
var = "birds are dying";
```

not like

```
*var= "birds are dying";
```

Comment: Compile with `-Wall -Wextra`. The warnings will tell you what's wrong. Also, [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/6699433) And you also might want to find a tutorial or something about pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is this the right way to assign a value to a variable created using
> malloc?

For starters there is no variable crated using malloc. Variables are created by declarations.

In this line

```
int *var = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 2)  ;
```

there is declared the variable `var` having the type `int *` that is initialized by the address of the dynamically allocated memory using `malloc` for two objects of the type `int`.

To access the dynamically allocated objects you can use the subscript operator like

```
var[0] = 22;
var[1] = 33;
```

that is the same if to write

```
*var = 22;
*( var + 1 ) = 33;
```

So to output the values of the allocated objects you can write

```
printf("%d \n" , *var);
```

or

```
printf("%d \n" , var[0]);
```

or

```
printf("%d \n" , var[1]);
```

or

```
printf("%d \n" , *( var + 1 ));
```

As for this code snippet

```
char *var;
var = "birds are dying";
```

then the variable `var` itself that is assigned with the address of the first character of the string literal `"birds are dying"` not an object that could be pointed to by the variable `var`.